# Basic question about direct sum of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, direct-sum

Let $V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$ be two subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^{4}$ such that $\mathbb{C}^{4} = V_{1}\oplus V_{2}$. Let $T$ be a $4\times 4$ complex matrix, viewed here as a linear operator on $\mathbb{C}^{4}$.

**Question:** Suppose $x$ is an eigenvector of $T$ associated to an eigenvalue $\alpha \neq 0$. Then, $Tx -\alpha x = 0$. On the other hand, if $x = x_{1}+x_{2}$, where $x_{i}\in V_{i}$, $i=1,2$, then:
$$Tx -\alpha x = Tx_{1}+Tx_{2} - \alpha x_{1} - \alpha x_{2} = 0$$
Does it follow that $Tx_{1} = \alpha x_{1}$ and $Tx_{2} = \alpha x_{2}$? If not, what condition should we have if we want this condition to hold?

Comment: The only plausible thing I can think of is to demand that one of $V_1$ and $V_2$ be an invariant subspaces under $T$, e.g., $T(V_1)\subset V_1$. Then you can have $T(x_1)=\alpha x_1$ and $x_2=0$.

Comment: In general, the answer is no. If you need an example, consider $V_1$ to be the $x_1,x_2$ plane and $V_2$ to be the $x_3,x_4$ plane and take $T$ to be the transformation with matrix
$$
T = \pmatrix{0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0}.
$$
Consider the eigenvector $x = (1,1,1,1)^T$.

Comment: @TedShifrin if $T(V_{1}) \subset V_{1}$ and $T(V_{2}) \subset V_{2}$ then the result stated in the post must hold, right?